# makemigrations failing with django_enumfield in Django 1.9

Tags: python, django, upgrade, typeerror

I just updated my Bitnami Django VM from 1.8.9 to 1.9.7. Everything was working smoothly before the upgrade, but now when I run makemigrations I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Couldn't reconstruct field role on rapid.GeoViewRole: __init__() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Here are the relevant classes/imports:

```
from django_enumfield import enum

class Role(enum.Enum):
     VIEWER = 0
     EDITOR = 1
     OWNER = 2

     labels = {
         VIEWER: 'Viewer',
         EDITOR: 'Editor',
         OWNER: 'Owner'
     }

class GeoViewRole(models.Model):
    token = models.ForeignKey(ApiToken)
    role = enum.EnumField(Role)
    geo_view = models.ForeignKey(GeoView)
    objects = models.GeoManager()
```

I can't figure out why I would be getting this error after the upgrade.

Comment: What is version of `django_enumfield`? Does it work with `django_enumfield==1.3b2`?

Comment: @VladimirDanilov Upgrading to 1.3b2 appears to have solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was the version of django-enumfield for me. I had

```
django-enumfield==1.2.1
```

Migrations worked after I removed it, and installed

```
django_enumfield==1.3b2
```